# IRT differences in using calibrated items and doing the calibration

Tags: r, item-response-theory

Recently I applied a mathematics test for *ensino fundamental* (the Brazilian elementary school) composed by 24 items previously calibrated under a 3 parameters logistic model. The calibration of these items goes back to 2008, and all items used was fit for the curriculum. The parameters (A is the discrimination, B the difficulty parameter and C is the guess parameter) of each item is displayed as follows

```
        A      B      C
0   0.000  0.000  0.000
1   1.244  2.081  0.204
2   1.913  0.936  0.162
3   1.590  1.071  0.285
4   1.298  2.777  0.351
5   0.560  1.029  0.135
6   1.003  2.027  0.229
7   0.763  1.938  0.311
8   1.485  0.472  0.038
9   1.189  2.748  0.270
10  0.545  1.839  0.171
11  0.000  0.000  0.000
12  1.820  3.301  0.235
13  1.310  0.497  0.117
14  1.453  2.477  0.253
15  0.628  1.212  0.233
16  3.994  2.085  0.174
17  1.189  2.119  0.358
18  1.653  1.671  0.156
19  1.778  1.606  0.218
20  1.672  0.720  0.178
21  1.866  0.804  0.286
22  1.294  1.750  0.262
23  1.244  0.922  0.249
```

There was 39 respondents and conditions of the calibration was reproduced (same test duration, same instructions and rules). Using `mirt`'s function `fscores` to obtain the traits of each student, it resulted in a list whose mean is`169.6` (translated to the scale where the mean is 250 and sd 50 for pedagogical interpretations). This result was far away from the historical scores of the school.

After I used `mirt` and `mirtCAT` to calibrate and obtain the proficiency of the students. Using the `generate.mirt_object` I generated a mirt object and `fscores` to obtain the abilities. The result was a list of parameters (A is the discrimination, B the difficulty parameter and C is the guess parameter) displayed as follows

```
            A          B         C
0   -0.908164  -0.888655  0.000011
1  -21.813855 -32.750073  0.158722
2   45.896688 -16.278915  0.178868
3   30.417857 -39.679219  0.633547
4   45.866596 -78.040571  0.276376
5   -0.167254  -0.599137  0.000325
6   58.881103 -53.035832  0.480787
7    1.345060   0.179426  0.000011
8   11.193242   8.704091  0.000020
9    4.812878  -3.405279  0.211483
10   0.851246  -0.472238  0.000014
11   0.684467  -2.301309  0.172352
12  18.404827 -37.285993  0.294857
13   7.040281   0.902891  0.570133
14  54.310470 -48.643073  0.328101
15   0.380293  -0.020780  0.000125
16   0.858722  -3.026284  0.128889
17   0.634882   0.109751  0.000026
18   0.644905  -0.001688  0.000015
19  45.394522 -77.356946  0.383602
20  58.895684 -52.991346  0.450317
21   1.814198  -0.383503  0.212582
22  59.468859 -18.015848  0.359025
23  45.549544 -77.591668  0.356788
```

and a list of abilities whose mean is `245.7` (translated to the scale where the mean is 250 and sd 50 for pedagogical interpretations). This result was consistent with the historical scores of these test in theses school. Also, the professors have confirmed the consistency of the data.

I'm new at IRT theory so I have no clue of what might have happened.

1. What factors have to be ensured to use pre-calibrated itens in order to obtain the traits?
2. These discrepancies is explained by the low number of respondents?
3. What could explain the assertivity of the second model for the traits?

Comment: The loadings on latent traits A and B (if that is what they are) look very strange to me. If these are on the log scale many of them are $\pm\infty$ on the raw scale. I suspect your second hypothesis is true and you have insufficient data to fit the second model.

Comment: @mdewey Sorry for the misconception, I will edit. A and B here stands for the discrimination parameter and the difficulty parameter respectively.

Comment: what was the sample size for the original 3PL model? moreover, the 39 respondents -- even if they had the same test conditions, do they match the original model based on demographics, etc?

Comment: Apologies for mis-reading but my point about $\pm\infty$ still applies to the parameter estimates.

Comment: @faustus the respondents live on the same state, studied under the same curriculum and are on the same grade of the students who have done the test for calibration.

Comment: @faustus I don't know the sample size for the calibration

Comment: A, B and C parameteres produced by you are on reporting metric (250/50?) or on 0/1-logit metric (A and B parameters don't really seem plausible in that case)?
If I understand correctly you recalibrated the items on 39 respondents of your recent study? Note that the suggested sample sizes for stable parameter estimation are way beyond that (1000 students for 3PL model).

Comment: Note that you have to set constraints on the parameters in order to identify the model. The reported parameters of items 1 and 11 in the original study seemed to be fixed to 0 during the item calibration. In your case the default behavior would most probably be to fix the regression-parameter of the random variable to 0 which more or less could translete into a mean of the ability-estimates of 245.7 when scaled to the 250/50 metric. As a result your freely estimated difficulty parameters are way below 0.

Comment: I would tend to trust the obtained mean of ability estimates of 169 from precalibrated item parameters. Please also look at the sum-scores and relative frequencies of correct answers to each of the items. There might be substantial reason why the mean score of the students if only 169.